# Japanese prepositional phrases

Tags: words, particles, resources

In the same way that in English and other languages as well there are groups of expressions classified as "prepositional phrases"

For example: "in spite of", "in response to", "in accordance with", "with regard to", "for the sake of", "by means of", etc.

**are Japanese expressions like the next ones classified under any denomination?**

～に照らして

～に従って

～に則って

～につれて／～につれ

～の代りに

～を押して／～を押し切って

～を機に／～を契機に

～を境に

～を経て

If so, **do you know if NINJAL or any other institution related with linguistics offer an exhaustive list of Japanese "prepositional phrases"** (in quotation marks waiting to know the correct denomination of the type of previous expressions)**?**

Comment: They are 副詞句 (adverbial phrases).

Comment: I don't think you could have an "exhaustive" list. Technically the amount of phrases you could make is infinite, it's just that the ones you listed are more idiomatic, but that does not prevent me make, say, "～を好物に" or "～を大事に" or "～を抑えて"(or with any noun/verb, it's just a normal structure) and use them as "prepositional phrases" or "adverbial phrases". Maybe mine are not so common, but 100% understandable and grammatical, so any list could only list out the common ones.

Answer (score 1):

The taxonomies vary between researchers (which can be said for a lot of things about Japanese). [This paper](http://repository.tufs.ac.jp/bitstream/10108/20000/1/jlc0320) mentions 複合辞 (compound particles), 後置詞 (postpositionals), 複合格助詞 (compound case particles), 格助詞相当句 (case particle equivalents). They might not be exactly the ones you are thinking about but seem close.

[現代語複合辞用例集](https://repository.ninjal.ac.jp/?action=repository_action_common_download&item_id=2322&item_no=1&attribute_id=22&file_no=1) contains a list with (technical) analysis.

There are other resources like 日本語複合辞用例データベース and BCCWJ複合辞辞書 (again, less educational than research oriented), but I don't think they are freely/easily accessible now.

There are fairly new scholarly books about them:

- https://www.izumipb.co.jp/book/b571981.html (2019)
- https://www.hituzi.co.jp/hituzibooks/ISBN978-4-89476-661-7.htm (2023)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will review closely the resources you refered to in the links. :)